# how to make property id as active in inmobi?

Tags: inmobi

I have added a property and added the live itunes url. But i am unable to verify my app in to active state. I am getting the error as
"Verification failed. Please enter the meta tag we generated within the HTML head tag and retry."

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Sohan from InMobi here.

To verify your iOS app, you will have to copy the HTML code snippet and paste it into the URL that is associated with your app on iTunes. This is for us to verify that you are indeed the creator of the app.

Do let me know if this works.